# xml database, is it good for the following?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, database

I am using a xml file as a database currently in development.

The xml file is going to be modified by multiple users over the network.(Not on a server per say but on my computer where they have access over the network)

I kinda know it is a bad idea to use xml for this but the structure of xml is much better/cleaner/something I like.

Wondering, what are my options ? As in would I be able to continue with the xml with some weird background custom connection ? (Which would verify all the necessary details to allow me to write/read from the xml without issues)

Or am I stuck in using some SQL type of database? If I am stuck in using that would there be some sort of database that is somewhat similar to XML...

EDIT: Reason for liking xml.
Grouped easily for the eyes.

```
<SomeDocument name="Something">
   <URL>bbbb</URL>
   <Something>2342</Soemthing>
   <Something_That_would_of_been_in_another_database>derp</...>
```

rather than linking 3-4 tables together...

Comment: Having just read the title of your question and not the details, the answer is "no."

Comment: why do you want a database that is similar to xml? what is the driver for that?

Comment: @MarcGravell, I edited to include reasoning.

Comment: but.... databases aren't *intended* for the eyes...?

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to use XML because it is easier to read. *You* won't be doing most of the reading, your software will.

Comment: Yup, you are both right. It's mostly because I wanted to explore xml and also I did not want to include any linking/associations from one database to the next. I knew the answer but u never know when there is some obscure way that's been hidden from everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to deal with concurrency issues if you used a file that several users had access to. Guarantees need to be made for one user not overwriting another user's changes made around the same time.

My suggestion is to use a proper database (e.g. SQL Server) that will handle these issues for you.

Comment: Anyway, Seems no answers are coming up anymore, So I will make this the solution as no alternate was shown... If anyone does update, I will update the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples of XML based databases that support multi-user environments. One is the OneNote Revision File Format used by Microsoft OneNote. Although there is a very detailed documentation on that, it is tremendously complicated to support multiple users editing a single file. Basically one could argue that an XML based storage is not viable option when you need multi-user support.

If you are stuck with the XML file you could look into the OneNote file format, but it isn't a traditional XML format, since it also uses a "binary wrapper", meaning that the actual content is defined in XML data within the binary file, but transactions/revisions/free chunks are represented binary. This is necessary since you have to allocate specific portions of the file for users to write to, while you have the file open.

If you don't want to use a dedicated server software, you could use various file-based databases like SQL CE or SQLite.

Comment: Good Stuff. Ain't going to make it more complicated but I will look into this, sounds fun.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the C# soultions, but for our java application we use [eXist-db](http://exist.sourceforge.net/) and query it with xquery. I'm not too familiar with it, but some use [markLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/). Still more use [Berkley db](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html).

Comment: The eXist-db looks like what I wanted but from there website I cannot see if they support anything more than JAva. The other ones, are products I would require to purchase and as this is a non-profitable software which is only for convenience, it wouldn't be good to purchase anything.

Comment: as far as I know, it is java only. They do have a very active mailing list -- http://exist.sourceforge.net/#mailinglists they have an IRC channel, but I have never had a need to utilize it.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether or not to use a native XML database, an XML-enabled database, a so-called NoSQL database, or any of the more traditional methods can rely on multiple factors. Just to mention two:

- Most importantly, do you have your data in XML, and do you want to keep it that way? If so, use an XML-enabled solution.
- Do you need scalability or performance? If so, you will need a solution that can deal with that. There are lots of NoSQL and XML databases that are well capable of handling that.

As for concurrency: any database should deal with that natively.

A number of databases have been mentioned already. To single out a few, MarkLogic Server ( www.marklogic.com ) is built to scale and perform upto Terabyte scale (and beyond), and has connectors for amongst others Java and .Net. The solution from 28msec ( www.28msec.com based on Zorba) runs in the cloud, and should scale too.

But most interesting to mention here is that these databases are often used through HTTP / REST interfaces. That allows easy integration from any programming language, and makes interchanging easier too.